# issues with firebase rules

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I am trying to write some simple firebase rules that will only allow the authenticated user to be able to write over their data.

```
{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      "uid": {
        ".read": true,
        ".write": "auth != null && auth.uid == uid"
// unknown variable uid.
      }
    }
  }
}
```

for some reason, I keep getting error above. The uid is inside so I don't get why there is a error?

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/rules-and-auth

Comment: "I keep getting error above" doesn't provide enough information so we can help. What exactly doesn't work? Do you have any errors? Please respond with @AlexMamo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To declare a [wildcard capture variable](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/core-syntax#wildcard_capture_variables) the name of the node needs to start with a `$`. So:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      "$uid": { //  add $ here
        ".read": true,
        ".write": "auth != null && auth.uid == $uid" //  now you can use the variable here
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Still the same issue! Trying to understand why

Comment: Ah yeah, I forgot to add the `$` in the rule itself too. I updated the code in my answer. Btw: the docs I linked have a quite clear example of this too.